# How can I send html mail and check user-agent with node.js

Tags: node.js, user-agent, html-email

I've creataed html activation mail. Now I need to send it to user. I've never work with node.js so I don't know how can I do it. Is there any code sample, that I can use? 
And one more questions about user agent. Can I check if a user access to my site from mobile or from desctop in nodejs.
Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related question on how to send email with node.js:

- [Sending emails in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/)

Here is a related question on how to check the user agent with node.js:

- [server-side browser detection? node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163350/)