# remove prefixes of css file on load

Tags: javascript, css, express, replace

In my application, I load a CSS files in the back-end (using Express.JS) and load it in the frontend.
However, before sending CSS code to the front-end application, I want to:

- Detect the user's browser;
- Edit the CSS code accordingly.

*For example, if user A uses Chrome, remove all lines that start with `-webkit-`.*

How can I detect the browser and edit the CSS code with the best performance?

***Note: My CSS code is formatted as beautified and not minified.***

Comment: Can you explain the reason of doing this? `gzip`ing your css files before sending to browser will be faster and more effective

Answer (score -1):

We can detect User's browser by using user agents. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163500/3226814) is the URL to the answer regarding how to detect user agent.

Now, unless changing content of your CSS file, make 2 different files for different browser types and write some condition on your page CSS link tag accordingly.

Comment: I can detect user browser agent but I want to edit the CSS code accordingly that I explained.

Comment: You know one thing, editing CSS on the go will make a little delay in the response to the user. This is not recommended.

Apart from that, the answer given by me is a suggestion and totally workable if you change the approach, so a negative vote is not justified.