# how to Redirect to another page in next.js based on css media query?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

im brand new to Next.js and i have the following situation. i want to redirect the user to the route `/messages` if he type route `/messages/123` based on css media query so if he is mobile we will not redirect and if he in browser then **redirect** .
i have tried the following code

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter, push } from 'next/router';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import Layout from '../components/Customer/Layout/Layout';
import Chat from '../components/Customer/Chat/Chat';

const Messages = () => {
 const { pathname, push } = useRouter();
 const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:1024px)');

 useLayoutEffect(() => {
   console.log('I am about to render!');
   if (matches && pathname === '/messages') {
     console.log('match!');
     push('/');
   }
 }, [matches, pathname, push]);

 return (
   <Layout currentURL={pathname}>
     <Chat />
   </Layout>
 );
};

export default Messages;
```

the problem is the component render twice before redirect

Answer (score 0):

But You should probably be using `useEffect` since you are not trying to do any DOM manipulations or calculations.

> **useLayoutEffect:** If you need to mutate the DOM and/or DO need to perform measurements
>
> **useEffect:** If you don't need to interact with the DOM at all or your DOM changes are unobservable (seriously, most of the time you should use this).

You should see immediate action.

**Edit:**

You can use Next JS `getInitialProps` to check the request headers and determine if the request if from mobile or desktop then redirect from there.

```
getInitialProps({ res, req }) {
    if (res) {
      // Test req.headers['user-agent'] to see if its mobile or not then redirect accordingly
      res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: '/message'
      })
      res.end()
    }
    return {}
  }
```

Comment: this is not the answer

Comment: @SolimanMahmoudSoliman You can check the headers in `getInitialProps` to determine if the request if from mobile or desktop.

Comment: how to check the headers @imu

Comment: @SolimanMahmoudSoliman You can use a library like https://github.com/etienne-martin/device-detector-js 

You will have to do string check on `req.headers['user-agent']` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163350/server-side-browser-detection-node-js