# How to get HTTP user-agent header with js?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

For my project, I want to get and print the user-agent of my browser. I'm using javascript (with node) to accomplish my goal. How can I get and print the user-agent header without using the HTTP module and html if possible and inside of this blank function:

```
function userAgent() {
  
}
```

Comment: [window.navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator)

Comment: Do you want to know what kind of browser users are accessing?

Comment: @MinwooKim yes, Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<script>
   window.onload = function () {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (agent.indexOf('chrome') != -1) { 
           alert('Chrome');
        }
        if (agent.indexOf('msie') != -1) {
           alert('Explorer');
        }
        if (agent.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
           alert('Safari');
        }
        if (agent.indexOf('firefox') != -1) {
           alert('Firefox');
        }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `window.navigator.userAgent`

```js
function userAgent() {
  return window.navigator.userAgent;
}

console.log(userAgent());
```

Comment: I get this error:
` return window.navigator.userAgent;`
  `^`

`ReferenceError: window is not defined`
I should clarify that I also don't want to use html for this

Comment: How do you run this code? Are you using Node maybe?

Comment: I am using node

Comment: Well, then you should definitely clarify that in the question because that changes like everything. You cannot get a user agent in the Node app itself because UA is something tightly connected with a **client app**. You could do that if you had for example some frontend app that makes a request to your Node server - then you can get the UA header **from the request**.

Comment: You have reference this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163350/server-side-browser-detection-node-js